# scheme of commuting matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be any field. Let $r$ and $n$ be two positive integers.

Consider the functor $F$ from the category of $k$-schemes to the category of sets which sends a $k$-scheme $T$ to the set of matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_r$ of dimension $n$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_T$ such that $A_i A_j = A_j A_i$ for all $i,j$.

This functor is clearly representable by an affine scheme, say $X = Spec (R)$.

What is known about the irreducible components of this scheme ?

What about if instead of $X$, we consider the scheme parametrizing commuting matrices with fixed determinants ?

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306275

Comment: For $r=2$ it's irreducible (Richardson's theorem, as I recall). For $r=3$ it's terrible even for fairly small $n$, because of the close connection with the Hilbert scheme of $n$ points in $\mathbb A^r$.

Comment: See intro of http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.4438 for state of the art bounds.